# How to mock `DateTime.now()` with `withClock` in Flutter (Dart)?

Tags: flutter, unit-testing, dart

I have a function that uses `DateTime.now()`

I want to mock this in my unit tests.

For this purpose, started to use the clock dart/flutter package
https://pub.dev/packages/clock/install

I do have this test code

```
import 'package:clock/clock.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:app/utils/time_manager.dart';

void main() {
  group('formatDateToRelative', () {
    final fakeClock = DateTime.parse('2018-02-07 13:55:59');
    void u(String caseName, String input, String expected) {
      test(caseName, () {
        final actual = withClock(Clock.fixed(fakeClock),
            () => TimeManager.formatDateToRelative(input));
        expect(actual, expected);
      });
    }

    u('other_week', '2018-02-15 13:55:59', '7 February 1:55 pm');
    u('other_week_same_day_name', '2018-02-14 00:00:00', '7 February 1:55 pm');
  });
}
```

and the source code under test is this one
`app/utils/time_manager.dart`

```
  static String formatDateToRelative(String date) {
    final now = DateTime.now();
    
    return 'doesntmatter for now';
```

I debug and the variable `now` above is always the current time and not the one I set with `withClock` to be `2018-02-07 13:55:59`

[image]

The screenshoot shows it visually as well I get the current date now=2022-10-17 11:34:34.645686 instead of the fixed clock 2018-02-07 13:55:59...

Am I doing something wrong ?

How can I mock the value of `DateTime.now()` during my flutter tests ?

Thank you

Comment: You cannot change the behavior of `DateTime.now()`.  The point of using `package:clock` is to add an abstraction layer that does support being mocked.  The expectation is that any code that you want to test and that depends on the current time should use `clock.now()` instead of `DateTime.now()`.

Comment: I see thank you jamesdlin. I read one blog post that was saying the proper way to mock DateTime.now() and misunderstood that the clock package was actually changing the system date for the unit test duration something like that. I need to change current time + timezone for my unit tests, so they are reproducible. Now I got it, will update my function to use clock.now() then

Comment: Do you know how to mock timezone and set it to UTC for the clock thingy ?

Comment: `DateTime` objects can be only in the local timezone or in UTC.  If you want UTC, use something like `withClock(Clock.fixed(DateTime.utc(...)), () { ... })`.  If you need to use non-local timezones that aren't UTC, you'd need to use a `TZDateTime` object from [`package:timezone`](https://pub.dev/packages/timezone).